# Need multiselection in GWT CellList

Tags: gwt, celllist

I would like to select multiple cells in a CellList component;
I'm new to GWT, someone please help.
In order to get multi selection, how do I modify the below code?

```
public class HelloWorld implements EntryPoint {
private static final List<String> DAYS = Arrays.asList("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
        "Friday", "Saturday");

public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a cell to render each value.
    TextCell textCell = new TextCell();

    // Create a CellList that uses the cell.
    CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(textCell);
    cellList.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.ENABLED);

    // Add a selection model to handle user selection.
    final SingleSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<String>();
    cellList.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
    selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
        public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
            String selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
            if (selected != null) {
                // Window.alert("You selected: " + selected);
            }
        }
    });

    cellList.setRowCount(DAYS.size(), true);

    // Push the data into the widget.
    cellList.setRowData(0, DAYS);

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get("gwtCellListBox").add(cellList);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried with below code for multiple selection and it worked well with _**Ctrl**_ key press & hold. But I would like to make this multi-selection using _**without**_ press & hold of _**Ctrl**_

Comment: final MultiSelectionModel<String> selectModel = new MultiSelectionModel<String>();
  cellList.setSelectionModel(selectModel);
  selectModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
   public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
    Set<String> selected = selectModel.getSelectedSet();
    if (selected != null) {
     //Window.alert("You selected: " + selected);
    }
   }
  });

Comment: I suggest you add a checkbox column for multiple selections, if you need help with that let me know.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need a `MultiSelectionModel`. Then, if you want to have hold the Ctrl key, use a `DefaultSelectionEventManager` as the `CellPreviewEvent.Handler` with a custom `EventTranslator` that always return `TOGGLE` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public class HelloWorld implements EntryPoint {
private static final List<String> DAYS = Arrays.asList("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday",
        "Friday", "Saturday");

public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a cell to render each value.
    TextCell textCell = new TextCell();

    // Create a CellList that uses the cell.
    CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(textCell);
    cellList.setKeyboardSelectionPolicy(KeyboardSelectionPolicy.ENABLED);

    // Add a selection model to handle user selection.
     final MultiSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = new MultiSelectionModel<String>();
     cellList.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
     selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
     public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {

        Set<String> selectedItems = selectionModel.getSelectedSet();

        for (String s : selectedItems) {
            System.out.println(s);
            Window.alert("You selected: " + s);
        }
    }
});

    cellList.setRowCount(DAYS.size(), true);

    // Push the data into the widget.
    cellList.setRowData(0, DAYS);

    // Add it to the root panel.
    RootPanel.get("gwtCellListBox").add(cellList);
}
}
```